# SqlBulkCopy with Column Mapping Outside The Bounds Exception in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, sqlbulkcopy, datareader

I'm running into an issue while using `SqlBulkCopy` to copy some data from Excel into a SQL Server table.

Basically, I need to copy all the contents from some of the rows of the Excel file into the table. I had this working using straight `SqlBulkCopy` with no column mapping, but only after modifying the Excel file (removing currently unused/empty columns). Due to our workflow, we need the Excel file to remain unchanged, so I tried using column mappings. (I prefer to avoid working with a staging table because my SQL skills aren't that great)

My code below works perfectly, except that it does not copy the final 11 columns. If I increase the final number (213) to 224 to try to include these, I get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` error.

The data reader says there is a field count of 212 (which is how many non-blank columns there are, but the actual total number of columns is 224. If I try without the column mapping, the data is off (to the right) by 12 columns.

```
using (DbConnection excelConnection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
            excelConnection.ConnectionString = connString;

            using (DbCommand command = excelConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Master List$A18:HD" + (17 + cusipcount) + "]";
                sqlConn.Open();
                excelConnection.Open();

                using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                    {
                        bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "Bond";
                        int i = 0;
                        for (int j = 0; j < 27; j++, i++)
                        {
                            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(j, i);
                        }
                        for (int j = 28; j < 94; j++, i++)
                        {
                            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(j, i);
                        }
                        for (int j = 105; j < 215; j++, i++)
                        {
                            bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(j, i);
                        }
                        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                    }
                }
                excelConnection.Close();

                sqlConn.Close();
            }
```

So basically I need that i to get up to 212, the j up to 224. I just can't figure out how to have my source index greater than 212 to grab the last 11 columns of data. It's like my column mapping is being limited by the the field count for some reason. Is there any way around this?

Comment: So either the data reader or the source object basically is skipping the blank columns.  Why not just go with the flow and treat it as if you have that many columns less?

Comment: That's what it seems like it's doing, but if I try without the column mapping or with
   
`for (int j = 0; j < 213; j++, i++)
                            {
                                bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(j, i);
                            }`
it reads in null values into my columns (thereby shifting the data right and leaving off the last 12 columns of data). I guess I could create blank columns in the my DB, but that seems pretty sloppy.

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug with the datareader when reading from excel?  I would suggest outputting the results from teh reader into a DataTable, then groom the DataTable (remove blank columns, or whatever you need), then use the DataTable as the source for bulk copy.

Comment: Thanks @DanLing...I tried that method and ran into the same problem which led to the realization that my query which I wrote months ago was the problem...HP not HD. Another humbling programming experience :P

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Feel free to answer your own question and check it off, and welcome to SO!

Comment: I would prefer specifying Column Names rather than depending on the Column Number. Have you tried that? If your sheet has a header row, that would be used for column names. Otherwise N1,n2,n3... or Col1, Col2, Col3... depending on the driver used. Have you given this a try?